# Add image to expo push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I want to send an expo push notification that would look like this :
[image]

That is to say add to the right of the notifications an image.
This is my code to generate notifications at the moment :

```js
 await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
                                    method: "POST",
                                    headers: {
                                        Accept: "application/json",
                                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                    },
                                    body: JSON.stringify({
                                        to: tokens,
                                        sound: 'default',
                                        badge: 1,
                                        title: "Actualité !",
                                        body: `${title} - ${commerce.name}`,
                                    }),
                                });
```

I can only add a title and a body but not an image...
How could I manage to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem. Maybe this will help yours too.

Here is the array:

```
(
            'to' => $req->device_token,

            'notification' => [
                'body' => $req->text,
                'title' => $req->title,
                'text' => $req->text,
                'sound' => 'default',
                'image' => $req->image
            ],
            'data' => [
                'item_type' => $req->type,
                'item_type_id' => $req->id,
                'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            ],
            'priority' => 'high',
)
```

Comment: I think this only works with Flutter and not with expo and react-native...

Answer (score 0):

for android it work out of the box whereas IOS we need to config manually in Xcode for prebuild https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images.

#### For eas build I still got an error on my SDK 49